# iframe in Angular4 not working

Tags: angular, iframe

I am trying to set up an iframe of a page in my Angular 4 app. I wanted to bring the interaction of the "iframed" page into my angular app.  The iframes display as it should, initially. But upon clicking "sign in" the iframe disappears.

Here is the code: (The link is defined in the component's typescript file)

```html
<iframe [src]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.link)' allowTransparency="true" frameborder"=10" width="80%"
      height="100vh"></iframe>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking a question, you will get much better answers if you provide code. Add what you have tried so far. Also please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

1. In order to use iframe use DomSanitizer in ts file
   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer);
2. Get the url like this:
   this.url = _sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(res.data.url);
3. Use url in iframe as tag src attribute

Comment: The problem is not showing the iframe. the iframe works. The problem is when i try to login in into the page that's iframed. the redirect page from the login page is not showing.